# Analog in Julia to coefficients() in R

Tags: julia

How can I extract coefficients from a GLM run in Julia. In R, I can fit a regression and just use coefficients():

```
lm.fit <- lm(y ~ . - 1, data = data.ols)
coefficients(lm.fit)
```

Is there a similar way to access coefficients in Julia so that I can use them in future formulas that I write?

My Julia code is:

```
olsFitFinal = fit(LinearModel, Y ~ -1 + Base + TRc + TCkRc + TcRc + R + RT,
                olsDat)
```

It seems that an answer at http://bit.ly/1EwSeCg implies the use of coefs() but that does not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing some more searching I found the solution:

```
coef(olsFitFinal)
```